# Get a char from a pointer to a string

Tags: c++, function, pointers, tolower

Hello I am trying to write a function that converts a string to lowercase by using a pointer instead of a return value.

```
void makeLowerCase(std::string* in){
//for loop tolower(char from *in);}
```

but I have no idea how to get each char out of my pointer to use tolower() with, or how to get how many chars are in the string as

```
*in.length()
```

and

```
sizeof(*in)/sizeof(char)
```

don't work for it. The former I get an error on the use of a pointer, the latter I get the same return value for `sizeof(*in)` so I don't even know how I would end my for loop.

Comment: Why not use a reference instead? `void makeLowerCase(std::string& in)`

Comment: If you are leveraging C++, you should use the libraries given inside of your function, but... outside of that statement, pass in the address of the `std::string` and then `in` will be a pointer you can manipulate.

Comment: Use `->` instead of `.` when working with pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has a shortcut to get the member of an object pointed to by a pointer:

```
in->length()
```

For accessing characters, use parentheses:

```
(*in)[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing by pointer and dealing with pointer syntax you can pass the string by reference and then you can use it just like a normal `std::string`.  If you have to use a pointer then you can either use

```
in->length();
```

or

```
(*in).length();
```

The parentheses are required in the second case as `.` has a higher precedence then `*`.

As for transforming the string to lower case you can use the built in functions from `<algorithm>` and and that would give you

```
void makeLowerCase(std::string& in)
{
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), in.begin(), ::tolower);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*in.length()
```

does not work because `.` has a higher precedence than `*`. Use parantheses:

```
(*in).length() 

sizeof(*in)/sizeof(char)
```

is the same as

```
sizeof(*in) / 1
```

because `sizeof(char) == 1`. `sizeof(*in) == sizeof(std::string)`, so this yields the size of the `std::string` object itsself, not the string of characters, which is implemention-defined.

---

This information, in combination with iterators, `for_each`, and lambdas, make for a pretty three-liner without any functions:

```
#include <cctype>

...

for (char& c : str)
    c = std::tolower(c);
```

---

Notes:

- **Use references instead.** They look better and are easier usable. Pointers should only be used in C++ for low-level stuff or when there's no way to cut them out.

Answer (score 0):

For pointers you would use the pointer operator. So that would be

```
in->length();
```

However a naked loop is not the ideal way (nor is using pointers to be honest).

A better way would be to use iterators to iterate through the string and convert it that way.

```
for (auto it=in->begin(); it!=in->end(); ++it) {
    *it = std::tolower(*it);
}
```